# How to create Dynamic Xpath for a Tag ? Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

Im trying to create 1 dynamic xpath for all 4 a tag which i need store in  a List to perform actions. Tomorrow it might be more Locators will be like that.

```
"//*[@id=\"ctl00_GridView\"]/tbody/tr[17]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a"
"//*[@id=\"ctl00_GridView\"]/tbody/tr[17]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a"
"//*[@id=\"ctl00_GridView\"]/tbody/tr[17]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a"
"//*[@id=\"ctl00_GridView\"]/tbody/tr[17]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a"
```

Need help to create dynamic xpath for that. Thank you all.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? In what language?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
row = 1

"//*[@id=\"ctl00_GridView\"]/tbody/tr[17]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[" + row + "]/a"
```

Then you could just increment/loop over "row" however you wish

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But it will not store all the element from WebPage to list, it will not find the next.

Comment: I provided you how to make an xPath dynamic, which is what you asked for.  You'd need to figure out how take that and store them to a list.  Hint: Create a list first, loop over the xPaths incrementing "row" each time by 1, append to list with each iteration

Comment: Thank you verify much

Answer (score 0):

use findelements with below locator

```
 "//*[@id=\"ctl00_GridView\"]/tbody/tr[17]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a"
```

it finds all td[*]/a elements

Answer (score 0):

First 4.

```
//*[@id=\"ctl00_GridView\"]/tbody/tr[17]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[position()<5]/a
```

All td in all trs.

```
//*[@id=\"ctl00_GridView\"]/tbody/tr[17]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a
```